# Using MS Graph API Data in PowerBI is not possible

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to connect my PowerBI Desktop with the MS Graph API to build a Dashboard where i can visualize Security/Compliance relevant changes in my Tenant. I already granted the relevant permissions to a licenced User.

When trying to obtain the Data i get an Error, that i don't have sufficient Permissions.

I think this Problem results not from the User Permissions but from the PowerBI permissions inside the GraphAPI.

Is there a way to grand PowerBI the relevat permissions as an app?

Btw. this does not work anymore: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCwCVbW6-Ww